# Enable REST on WSO2 Business Rule Server

Tags: rest, wsdl, wso2, business-rules

I'm working on Wso2 business rule management solution (Wso2 brs), and I have successfuly completed the steps for creating a first rule : https://docs.wso2.com/display/BRS220/Creating+and+Deploying+the+Rule+Service

The rule is currently reachable by using the SOAP protocol, but I'd like to use REST. I see in the documentation that there must be a way to achieve this ( https://docs.wso2.com/display/BRS220/Features ), but I don't found any indication of how to do it on BRS.

Here is some lines of my wsdl definition :

```
<wsdl2:service name="OrderApprovalService" interface="tns:ServiceInterface">
    <wsdl2:endpoint name="OrderApprovalServiceHttpsEndpoint" binding="tns:OrderApprovalServiceHttpBinding" address="https://10.130.3.70:9443/services/OrderApprovalService.OrderApprovalServiceHttpsEndpoint/"/>
    <wsdl2:endpoint name="OrderApprovalServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="tns:OrderApprovalServiceSoap12Binding" address="http://10.130.3.70:9763/services/OrderApprovalService.OrderApprovalServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
    <wsdl2:endpoint name="OrderApprovalServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint" binding="tns:OrderApprovalServiceSoap12Binding" address="https://10.130.3.70:9443/services/OrderApprovalService.OrderApprovalServiceHttpsSoap12Endpoint/"/>
    <wsdl2:endpoint name="OrderApprovalServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="tns:OrderApprovalServiceSoap11Binding" address="http://10.130.3.70:9763/services/OrderApprovalService.OrderApprovalServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
    <wsdl2:endpoint name="OrderApprovalServiceHttpEndpoint" binding="tns:OrderApprovalServiceHttpBinding" address="http://10.130.3.70:9763/services/OrderApprovalService.OrderApprovalServiceHttpEndpoint/"/>
    <wsdl2:endpoint name="OrderApprovalServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint" binding="tns:OrderApprovalServiceSoap11Binding" address="https://10.130.3.70:9443/services/OrderApprovalService.OrderApprovalServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/"/>
</wsdl2:service>
```

I see that there is a "OrderApprovalServiceHttpsEndpoint" and a "OrderApprovalServiceHttpEndpoint" that could correspond to a REST webservice, but all my attempts to reaching them have failed. If I attempt to send this model in POST request :

```
<OrderApprovalRequest>
    <placeOrder>
        <price>7</price>
        <quantity>7</quantity>
        <symbol>Company A</symbol>
    </placeOrder>
</OrderApprovalRequest>
```

I get an error 500 :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.handleFault(AxisServlet.java:427)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.processAxisFault(AxisServlet.java:398)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:188)
    org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
```

Is there anyone here who already succeed to do this ? Or who know if this is possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try your scenario with the TryIt tool for the service. https://docs.wso2.com/display/BRS200/Testing+WSDLs
You can pick the HTTP endpoint in there and capture the messages it generated and use those against the endpoint using curl and try.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for you reply. But I already try this, and this seems to work only with SOAP services.